# Cant view service accounts calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Using the following code I am unable to view add a service accounts calendar to my profile. When I try I get the message "you don't have access to {service account email}'s Callender. Is there anything else I have to do view a service accounts calender?

```
var calender = new Calendar()
            {
                Description = "calendar",
                Summary = "calendar",
                TimeZone = "America/New_York"
            };
            Calendar createdCalendar = service.Calendars.Insert(calender).Execute();
            var rule = new AclRule()
            {
                Role = "reader",
                Scope = new AclRule.ScopeData()
                {
                    Type = "default"
                }
            };
            service.Acl.Insert(rule, createdCalendar.Id).Execute();
            var services = service.Acl.List(createdCalendar.Id).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out you don't add the calendar using your service accounts email, you use the calenders id.